# "DX11 feature level 10.0 is required" but the computer already has feature level 10_0

Tags: windows-10, directx

While trying to run Valorant on my computer, the engine doesn't run giving a message:
[image]

But my computer's GPU and Drivers both already support Feature level 10_0:
[image]

CPU: Intel i3-2330M
DirectX version: 12
Windows 10

Comment: Your iGPU is incapable of running DX 12.  It doesn't have the necessary hardware to do so.  The feature levels, per your dxdiag, indicate your display drivers are not providing the necessary DirectX 11 feature level.  If you were running the current Windows 10 with the appropriate driver, your WDDM version would be 2.9.  WDDM 1.2 is the basic display driver.  You might check the Intel website for newer drivers consider they are from 2016 which is 6 years ago.  Since Intel does not have Windows 10 drivers for your iGPU there isn't a solution to your problem. Valorant cannot run on your PC

Comment: The Intel HD 3000 has no real Windows 10 support at all. There was one token driver released in 2015, updated 2016, after that it was dropped completely by Intel & MS. See https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=intel%20hd%203000 [Intel didn't want to support it at all, but they got their arm twisted a bit. This was the one concession] It definitely has no support in current Win 10. It became abandonware late 2016.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [minimum system requirements of Valorant](https://playvalorant.com/en-us/specs/) state that you need a “Intel HD 4000”, which probably refers to the Ivy Bridge Intel HD Graphics 4000 iGPU. That’s one generation more recent than what you have. It supports DirectX 11.1 (11_0).

It’s very likely the error message text was not updated properly and that Valorant actually requires Feature Level 11_0 (feature levels don’t have a period in them).

Answer (score 0):

> My computer's GPU and Drivers both already support Feature level 10_0

Valorant actually requires Feature Level 11_0, not 10_0, in order to run.

Intel® HD Graphics 2000/3000 only supports DX 10_1 and OpenGL 3.1

[image]

Source: [Supported APIs for Intel® Graphics](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005524/graphics.html)